# Требуется сделать загрузчик классов для java

Tags: java

Требуется сделать загрузчик классов из файла для java.

Я слышал что это делается с помощью переопределения ClassLoader операторов, как это можно сделать?

В интернете не одной нормальной инструкции.

Comment: Что значит выполнить класс? Реализовывать свой Classloader это где-то выше адвансед уровня знания Java, а то что вам надо это видимо JavaCompiler API, копайте в эту сторону.

Comment: Поправил) нет мне не надо сделать свой Classloader, мне надо сделать Classloader который работает как обычный Classloader но грузит классы из файла.

Comment: Т.е. вам надо реализовать свой ClassLoader) А дефолтный откуда по вашему грузит?

Comment: @Vartlok, Не особенно и advanced.

Comment: @Nofate да? ну тогда может поделитесь мудростью =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Нашёл очень даже неплохой пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6219855/980828). Жаль только, что ссылка на оригинал битая.

Вариант - использовать URL:

```
// Создайте объект File в корне директории, которая содержит class-файл.
File file = new File("c:\\myclasses\\");

try {
    // Преобразуйте File в URL
    URL url = file.toURI().toURL();          // file:/c:/myclasses/
    URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};

    // Создайте новый class loader с директорией
    ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

    // Загрузите класс; MyClass.class должен располагаться в
    // директории file:/c:/myclasses/com/mycompany
    Class cls = cl.loadClass("com.mycompany.MyClass");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
}
```

Comment: Так просто?? Я тестировать

Comment: Да, все отлично работает) хороший пример.